# Job For Wordpress by blueglass plugin apply button validation API

Tags: javascript, wordpress

i want to insert following Java Script into my Wordpress plugin
please help me

this what i written which validate from Sheetsu API
Details at - https://codepen.io/santosh-panda/pen/YOedWv?editors=1010

```
<input id="input-text_flacement-id">
<script src="https://script.sheetsu.com/"></script>

<script>
  var input = document.getElementById('input-text_flacement-id');
    var is_focused = false;

    input.onfocus = function () {
        is_focused = true;
    }

    input.onblur = function () {
        if (is_focused) {
            is_focused = false;
            check_id(input.value);
        }
    }

    function check_id(id) {
        if (id.match(/\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4}/)) {
            document.body.append("\nchecking...");
            function successFunc(data) {
                var row = data.filter((row)=>row['adhar_no'] == id)
                if(row.length){
                    document.body.append("\nid found");
                }
                else{
                    document.body.append('\nid not found');
                }
            }
            // Get all rows where column 'adhar_no' is '3894-8873-7149'
            var searchQuery = {
                status: 'active',
            };
            Sheetsu.read("https://sheetsu.com/apis/v1.0dh/dd98887de543/", {
                search: searchQuery
            }, successFunc);
        }
        else {
            document.body.append('\ninvalid id');
        }
    }
</script>
```

this code ^^ want to inster in Wordpress plugin JS
which excutive in http://www.flacement.com/jobssearch/iffco-tokio-job-in-jharsuguda/
i want it when some one apply [apply text field [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4cqp.png)
in flacement ID it should validate from JS API if found then procedd or if not then invalide as first code. code is ready but i am confuse where to instert in follwing so it start working

```
Number.prototype.clamp = function(min, max) {
    return Math.min(Math.max(this, min), max);
};

(function($){
    $.fn.filterFind = function(selector) { 
        return this.find('*')         // Take the current selection and find all descendants,
                   .addBack()         // add the original selection back to the set 
                   .filter(selector); // and filter by the selector.
    };

    $.fn.svgDraw = function(progress) {
        this.filterFind('path').each(function() {
            var pathLength = this.getTotalLength();
            $(this).css('strokeDasharray', pathLength + ' ' + pathLength);
            $(this).css('strokeDashoffset', pathLength * ((1 - progress)).clamp(0, 1));
        });

        return this;
    };

    $(document).ready(function(){

        if( $('.jobs-modal').length ){

            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.jobs-modal').removeClass('hide');
            }, 500);

            $('.jp-apply-button').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                $('body').addClass('jobs-modal-open');
                $('.jobs-modal').addClass('open');
            });

            $('.jobs-modal .modal-close').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).parents('.jobs-modal').removeClass('open');
                $('body').removeClass('jobs-modal-open');
            });

            $('.jobs-modal-content').each(function(k){


                $(this).find( '.inputfile' ).each(function(k){

                    var label    = this.nextElementSibling;
                    var labelVal = label.innerHTML;

                    $(this).change(function(e){
                        var fileName = '';
                        if( this.files && this.files.length > 2 )
                            fileName = ( this.getAttribute( 'data-multiple-caption' ) || '' ).replace( '{count}', this.files.length );
                        else
                            fileName = e.target.value.split( '\\' ).pop();

                        if( fileName ){
                            label.querySelector( 'span' ).innerHTML = fileName;
                            var num = $(this).parents('.modal-input-fileinput').attr('data-files');
                            num = Number(num) + 1;
                            $(this).parents('.modal-input-fileinput').attr('data-files', num);
                        }else{
                            label.innerHTML = labelVal;
                        }
                    });

                    $(this).focus(function(){ $(this).addClass('has-focus') });
                    $(this).blur(function(){ $(this).removeClass('has-focus') });
                });

            });


            if( $('.choose_file_multi_add').length ){
                var i = 1;
                $('.choose_file_multi_add').click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();

                    var key_id = $(this).data('key');

                    var parent = $(this).parents('.modal-input-fileinput');
                    var input = $('#file-input-tpl-'+key_id).html();
                    var label = $('#file-label-tpl-'+key_id).html();

                    var id =  key_id + '-'+i;
                    var key = key_id + '-key-'+i;

                    input = input.replace( '{id}', id ).replace( '{id}', id ).replace( '{id}', id );
                    input = input.replace( '{nr}', i ).replace( '{nr}', i ).replace( '{nr}', i );
                    input = input.replace( '{key}', key ).replace( '{key}', key ).replace( '{key}', key );

                    label = label.replace( '{id}', id ).replace( '{id}', id ).replace( '{id}', id );

                    $(input).insertBefore( $('#'+key_id+' .choose_file_multi_add') );
                    $(label).insertBefore( $('#'+key_id+' .choose_file_multi_add') );
                    //parent.prepend( input );
                    //parent.prepend( label );

                    $('#'+id).change(function(e){
                        var fileName = '';
                        if( this.files && this.files.length > 1 )
                            fileName = ( this.getAttribute( 'data-multiple-caption' ) || '' ).replace( '{count}', this.files.length );
                        else
                            fileName = e.target.value.split( '\\' ).pop();


                        if( fileName ){
                            $('#label-'+id).find('span.name').text( fileName );
                            var num = $(this).parents('.modal-input-fileinput').attr('data-files');
                            num = Number(num) + 1;
                            $(this).parents('.modal-input-fileinput').attr('data-files', num);
                        }
                    });


                    $('.choose_file_multi .remove').click(function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var id = $(this).parents('.choose_file_multi').attr('id');
                        id = id.replace('label-', 'jobgroup-');

                        var num = $(this).parents('.modal-input-fileinput').attr('data-files');
                        num = Number(num) - 1;
                        $(this).parents('.modal-input-fileinput').attr('data-files', num);

                        $('.'+id).remove();

                        recalculateInputs();

                        return false;
                    });

                    $('#'+id).click();

                    recalculateInputs();

                    i++;
                });
            }

            function recalculateInputs(){
                if( $('.modal-input-fileinput.multiple .modal-input-multifile').length == 0 ){
                    $('.disabled-file-placeholder').addClass('input-reqired');
                }else{
                    $('.disabled-file-placeholder').removeClass('input-reqired');
                }
            }

            function validateEmail(email) {
                var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
                return re.test(email);
            }

            var sending_form = false;

            $('.progress-button .progress-circle').svgDraw(0);

            $("form#jobs-modal-form").submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                var self        = this;
                var toreturn    = true;
                $('#jobs-modal-form .input-reqired').each(function(){
                    var value = $(this).val();

                    var is_checked = false;

                    if( $(this).hasClass('input-job_email') ){
                        if( value == '' || !validateEmail(value) ){
                            $(this).addClass('alert').parents('.jobs-modal-input').addClass('alert');
                            toreturn = false;
                        }else{
                            $(this).removeClass('alert').parents('.jobs-modal-input').removeClass('alert');
                        }
                    }else if( $(this).hasClass('modal-input-checkbox') ){
                        var checkboxes_checked = 0;
                        $(this).parents('.checkbox_field').find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
                            var checked = $(this).prop('checked');
                            if( checked == true ){
                                checkboxes_checked++;
                            }
                        });

                        if( checkboxes_checked == 0 ){
                            $(this).addClass('alert').parents('.jobs-modal-input').addClass('alert');
                            toreturn = false;
                        }else{
                            $(this).removeClass('alert').parents('.jobs-modal-input').removeClass('alert');
                        }

                    }else if( $(this).hasClass('modal-input-radio') ){
                        var checkboxes_checked = 0;
                        $(this).parents('.radio_field').find('input[type="radio"]').each(function(){
                            var checked = $(this).prop('checked');
                            if( checked == true ){
                                checkboxes_checked++;
                            }
                        });

                        if( checkboxes_checked == 0 ){
                            $(this).addClass('alert').parents('.jobs-modal-input').addClass('alert');
                            toreturn = false;
                        }else{
                            $(this).removeClass('alert').parents('.jobs-modal-input').removeClass('alert');
                        }

                    }else{
                        if( value == '' ){
                            $(this).addClass('alert').parents('.jobs-modal-input').addClass('alert');
                            toreturn = false;
                        }else{
                            $(this).removeClass('alert').parents('.jobs-modal-input').removeClass('alert');
                        }
                    }

                });

                var input = document.getElementById('input-text_flacement-id');
    var is_focused = false;

    input.onfocus = function () {
        is_focused = true;
    }

    input.onblur = function () {
        if (is_focused) {
            is_focused = false;
            check_id(input.value);
        }
    }

    function check_id(id) {
        if (id.match(/\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4}/)) {
            document.body.append("\n checking...");

            function successFunc(data) {
                var row = data.filter((row)=>row['adhar_no'] == id)

                if(row.length){
                    document.body.append("\n id found");
                }
                else{
                    document.body.append('\n id not found');
                }
            }
            // Get all rows where column 'adhar_no' is '3894-8873-7149'

            var searchQuery = {
                status: 'active',
            };
            Sheetsu.read("https://sheetsu.com/apis/v1.0dh/dd98887de543/", {
                search: searchQuery
            }, successFunc);

        } else {
            document.body.append('\n invalid id');
        }
    }


                if( toreturn && sending_form == false ){
                    /*
                    var progressBTN = $(self).find('.progress-button');
                    progressBTN.addClass('loading');

                    var progressCRCL = $(self).find('.progress-circle');
                    var progress = 0;

                    var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
                        progress += Math.random() * 0.5;
                        progressCRCL.svgDraw(progress);

                        if(progress >= 1) {
                            clearInterval(intervalId);
                        }
                    }, 200);
                    */

                    sending_form = true;
                    $('.job-submit').hide();
                    $('.jobs-sending').show();

                    var formData    = new FormData($("form#jobs-modal-form")[0]);

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: jpsd.ajaxurl,
                        data: formData, 
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,

                        success: function (data) {

                            //clearInterval(intervalId);
                            //progressCRCL.svgDraw(1);

                            // Clear all smaces and newlines that can happen on response on some servers
                            data = data.replace(/\s/g, "");

                            if( data == 'ok' ){

                                //setTimeout(function(){
                                //  $(self).find('.progress-button').addClass('success');
                                //}, 500);

                                //setTimeout(function(){
                                    $(self).slideUp();
                                    $('#job-apply-confirmation').slideDown();
                                //}, 1000);

                            }else{

                                //setTimeout(function(){
                                //  $(self).find('.progress-button').addClass('error');
                                //}, 500);

                                //setTimeout(function(){
                                    $('.jobs-sending').hide();
                                //}, 1000);
                            }

                            return false;
                        },
                    });


                    return false;
                }

                return false;
            });


            /*
            $('.progress-button').on('click', function() {
                var $button = $(this);
                $(this).addClass('loading');

                var $progress = $(this).find('.progress-circle');
                var progress = 0;
                var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
                    progress += Math.random() * 0.5;
                    $progress.svgDraw(progress);

                    if(progress >= 1) {
                        clearInterval(intervalId);
                        //console.log("cleared interval");
                        $button.removeClass('loading');
                        if($button.attr('data-result') == "true") {
                            $button.addClass('success');
                        }
                        else {
                                $button.addClass('error');
                        }

                    }
                }, 300);

                // Now that we finished, unbind
                $(this).off('click');
            });
            */


        } // end .jobs-modal length

    });


})(jQuery);
```

Comment: no body want to help me :(

Comment: Hello Flacement, Welkom to stackoverflow. Give it some time. If you feel like your not getting enough attention to you question, you might want to edit your question to include more information. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask sums up all things that might be helpfull for others to help faster/better